# Как исправить проблему псевдоэлементов на ios?

Tags: html, css

добавляется непонятный бордер

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```js
$(document).on('click', '.reg__box', function() {
    $(".reg__elem").removeClass("reg__elem--active");
    $(this).parents(".reg__elem").addClass("reg__elem--active");
    var index = $(this).parents(".reg__elem").index();
    console.log(index);
    $(".reg__desc").hide(0).eq(index).fadeIn(0);
  })
```

```css
.reg__tabs {
    --tab-background: #f7fafc;
    --tab-text-color: #fff8f8;
    --tab-radius: 24px;
    --tab-padding: 20px;
    width: calc(100% + 24px);
    margin-left: -12px;
}

.reg__head {
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.reg__elem {
    width: 50%;
    padding-top: 12px;
    padding-right: 12px;
    position: relative;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-self: end;
    width: 50%;
    border-radius: var(--tab-radius) var(--tab-radius) 0 0;
}

.reg__elem:after,
.reg__elem:before {
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    width: var(--tab-radius);
    height: var(--tab-radius);
}

.reg__elem.reg__elem--active {
    background-color: var(--tab-background);
}

.reg__elem.reg__elem--active:not(:first-child)::before {
    right: 100%;
    background: 100% 100%/var(--tab-radius) var(--tab-radius) radial-gradient(var(--tab-radius) circle at 0 0, transparent calc(100% - 2px), var(--tab-background) 100%) no-repeat;
}

.reg__elem.reg__elem--active:not(:last-child)::after {
    left: 100%;
    background: 100% 100%/var(--tab-radius) var(--tab-radius) radial-gradient(var(--tab-radius) circle at 100% 0, transparent calc(100% - 2px), var(--tab-background) 100%) no-repeat;
}

.reg__desc {
    z-index: 2;
    padding: var(--tab-padding);
    border-radius: var(--tab-radius);
    background: var(--tab-background);
}

.reg__desc:first-child {
    border-radius: 0 var(--tab-radius) var(--tab-radius) var(--tab-radius);
}

.reg__desc:last-child {
    border-radius: var(--tab-radius) 0 var(--tab-radius) var(--tab-radius);
}

.reg__box {
    cursor: pointer;
    width: 100%;
    position: relative;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    border: 1px solid #e9e8f4;
    border-radius: 15px;
    background-color: #fff;
    margin-left: 12px;
    margin-bottom: 24px;
}

.reg__icon {
    display: block;
    width: 38px;
    height: 38px;
}

.reg__icon img {
    display: block;
}

.reg__content {
    display: block;
    width: calc(100% - 38px);
    padding-left: 16px;
    padding-right: 45px;
    pointer-events: none;
}

.reg__change,
.reg__time,
.reg__text {
    display: block;
}

.reg__input {
    display: none;
}

.reg__input:checked + label:after {
    border: 4px solid #3453f3;
}

.reg__label {
    cursor: pointer;
    display: flex;
    width: 100%;
    align-items: center;
    padding: 15px 20px;
    padding-right: 10px;
}

.reg__label:after {
    position: absolute;
    content: ' ';
    top: 50%;
    transform: translateY(-50%);
    right: 18px;
    width: 18px;
    height: 18px;
    border: 1px solid #e9e8f4;
    border-radius: 20px;
}

*{box-sizing: border-box;}

body {
  padding: 20px;
}
```

```html
<div class="reg__tabs">
  <div class="reg__head">
    <div class="reg__elem reg__elem--active">
      <div class="reg__box">
        <input type="radio" checked="" id="r_courier" class="reg__input" name="delivery">
        <label for="r_courier" class="reg__label">
          <span class="reg__icon">
            <img src="img/order/delivery_courier.svg" alt="">
          </span>
          <span class="reg__content">
            <span class="reg__change">title 1</span>
            <span class="reg__time">c 09:00 до 20:00</span>
            <span class="reg__text">text 1</span>
          </span>
        </label>

      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="reg__elem">
      <div class="reg__box">
        <input type="radio" id="r_nova" class="reg__input" name="delivery">
        <label for="r_nova" class="reg__label">
          <span class="reg__icon">
            <img src="img/order/nova_poshta.svg" alt="">
          </span>
          <span class="reg__content">
            <span class="reg__change">Доставка</span>
            <span class="reg__time">1 - 3 дня</span>
            <span class="reg__text">text2</span>
          </span>
        </label>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <!--end reg__holder-->
  <div class="reg__body">
    <div class="reg__desc" style="">
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor, sit amet consectetur, adipisicing elit. Consectetur ex sapiente officiis, explicabo fugiat ipsam laborum dolorum culpa voluptatum dolore, repellendus, aspernatur autem amet doloribus eos exercitationem saepe perspiciatis molestias!</p>
    </div>
    <div class="reg__desc" style="display: none;">
      <p>22Lorem ipsum dolor, sit amet consectetur, adipisicing elit. Consectetur ex sapiente officiis, explicabo fugiat ipsam laborum dolorum culpa voluptatum dolore, repellendus, aspernatur autem amet doloribus eos exercitationem saepe perspiciatis molestias!</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Уточните, пожалуйста, про какой border идёт речь. ИМХО в предложенном коде всё выглядит весьма достойно.

Comment: @7-zete-7, показала стрелкой

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Когда в градиенте делаете смещение на 2px `.reg__elem.reg__elem--active:not(:first-child)::before, .reg__elem.reg__elem--active:not(:last-child)::after` то и делаете смещение и во втором параметре цвета

Поправил - должно работать

```js
$(document).on('click', '.reg__box', function() {
    $(".reg__elem").removeClass("reg__elem--active");
    $(this).parents(".reg__elem").addClass("reg__elem--active");
    var index = $(this).parents(".reg__elem").index();
    console.log(index);
    $(".reg__desc").hide(0).eq(index).fadeIn(0);
  })
```

```css
.reg__tabs {
    --tab-background: #f7fafc;
    --tab-text-color: #fff8f8;
    --tab-radius: 24px;
    --tab-padding: 20px;
    width: calc(100% + 24px);
    margin-left: -12px;
}

.reg__head {
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.reg__elem {
    width: 50%;
    padding-top: 12px;
    padding-right: 12px;
    position: relative;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-self: end;
    width: 50%;
    border-radius: var(--tab-radius) var(--tab-radius) 0 0;
}

.reg__elem:after,
.reg__elem:before {
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    width: var(--tab-radius);
    height: var(--tab-radius);
}

.reg__elem.reg__elem--active {
    background-color: var(--tab-background);
}

.reg__elem.reg__elem--active:not(:first-child)::before {
    right: 100%;
    background: calc(100% + 2px) 100%/var(--tab-radius) var(--tab-radius) radial-gradient(var(--tab-radius) circle at 0 0, transparent calc(100% - 2px), var(--tab-background) calc(100% - 2px) ) no-repeat;
}

.reg__elem.reg__elem--active:not(:last-child)::after {
    left: 100%;
    background: calc(100% - 2px) 100%/var(--tab-radius) var(--tab-radius) radial-gradient(var(--tab-radius) circle at 100% 0, transparent calc(100% - 2px), var(--tab-background) calc(100% - 2px)) no-repeat;
}

.reg__desc {
    z-index: 2;
    padding: var(--tab-padding);
    border-radius: var(--tab-radius);
    background: var(--tab-background);
}

.reg__desc:first-child {
    border-radius: 0 var(--tab-radius) var(--tab-radius) var(--tab-radius);
}

.reg__desc:last-child {
    border-radius: var(--tab-radius) 0 var(--tab-radius) var(--tab-radius);
}

.reg__box {
    cursor: pointer;
    width: 100%;
    position: relative;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    border: 1px solid #e9e8f4;
    border-radius: 15px;
    background-color: #fff;
    margin-left: 12px;
    margin-bottom: 24px;
}

.reg__icon {
    display: block;
    width: 38px;
    height: 38px;
}

.reg__icon img {
    display: block;
}

.reg__content {
    display: block;
    width: calc(100% - 38px);
    padding-left: 16px;
    padding-right: 45px;
    pointer-events: none;
}

.reg__change,
.reg__time,
.reg__text {
    display: block;
}

.reg__input {
    display: none;
}

.reg__input:checked + label:after {
    border: 4px solid #3453f3;
}

.reg__label {
    cursor: pointer;
    display: flex;
    width: 100%;
    align-items: center;
    padding: 15px 20px;
    padding-right: 10px;
}

.reg__label:after {
    position: absolute;
    content: ' ';
    top: 50%;
    transform: translateY(-50%);
    right: 18px;
    width: 18px;
    height: 18px;
    border: 1px solid #e9e8f4;
    border-radius: 20px;
}

*{box-sizing: border-box;}

body {
  padding: 20px;
}
```

```html
<div class="reg__tabs">
  <div class="reg__head">
    <div class="reg__elem reg__elem--active">
      <div class="reg__box">
        <input type="radio" checked="" id="r_courier" class="reg__input" name="delivery">
        <label for="r_courier" class="reg__label">
          <span class="reg__icon">
            <img src="img/order/delivery_courier.svg" alt="">
          </span>
          <span class="reg__content">
            <span class="reg__change">title 1</span>
            <span class="reg__time">c 09:00 до 20:00</span>
            <span class="reg__text">text 1</span>
          </span>
        </label>

      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="reg__elem">
      <div class="reg__box">
        <input type="radio" id="r_nova" class="reg__input" name="delivery">
        <label for="r_nova" class="reg__label">
          <span class="reg__icon">
            <img src="img/order/nova_poshta.svg" alt="">
          </span>
          <span class="reg__content">
            <span class="reg__change">Доставка</span>
            <span class="reg__time">1 - 3 дня</span>
            <span class="reg__text">text2</span>
          </span>
        </label>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <!--end reg__holder-->
  <div class="reg__body">
    <div class="reg__desc" style="">
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor, sit amet consectetur, adipisicing elit. Consectetur ex sapiente officiis, explicabo fugiat ipsam laborum dolorum culpa voluptatum dolore, repellendus, aspernatur autem amet doloribus eos exercitationem saepe perspiciatis molestias!</p>
    </div>
    <div class="reg__desc" style="display: none;">
      <p>22Lorem ipsum dolor, sit amet consectetur, adipisicing elit. Consectetur ex sapiente officiis, explicabo fugiat ipsam laborum dolorum culpa voluptatum dolore, repellendus, aspernatur autem amet doloribus eos exercitationem saepe perspiciatis molestias!</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: спасибо огромное